# Prestashop header add icons/links not clickable

Tags: header, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I need some help with header icons. I add icons near logo, and i want to make them with link, but they are not working.I can click on logo, but I can't click on them.
Here is the part of code: 
`<a id="header_logo" href="{$base_dir}" title="{$shop_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
                    <img class="logo" style="margin-bottom:10px;" src="https://www.irankiuparduotuve.lt/img/irankiu-parduotuve.png" alt="{$shop_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.irankiuparduotuve.lt/info/kaip-pirkti/#4">
                    <img style="margin-bottom:10px; position: absolute; top: 13%; left: 23%;" src="https://www.irankiuparduotuve.lt/img/saugu.png" alt="Saugu pirkti!" />
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.irankiuparduotuve.lt/info/kaip-pirkti/#7">
                    <img style="margin-bottom:10px; position: absolute; top: 13%; left: 31%;" src="https://www.irankiuparduotuve.lt/img/pristatymas.png" alt="Pristatymas visoje Lietuvoje!" />
                </a>`

And this is how it looks like on website [image: I can only click first logo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's probably cause by poorly written CSS rules. Your logos are positioned using `position:absolute;`,which is causing all the trouble. The anchor element `<a>` is positioned statically, meanwhile the image inside is `position:absolute;`. Therefore, the anchor element doesnt have any height or width and is unclickble.

What you can do is edit the CSS rules for anchor and image tags:

```
<a href="https://www.irankiuparduotuve.lt/info/kaip-pirkti/#7" style="
  z-index: 11; margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute; top: 13%;
  left: 31%; display: inline-block;"> 

<img style="/* margin-bottom:10px; */ /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 13%; */ /* left: 31%; */
  /* display: inline-block; */" 
src="https://www.irankiuparduotuve.lt/img/pristatymas.png">

</a>
```

Sorry for poor formatting. Basically you need to apply yout positionin rules to `<a>` element, not the `<img>`

Sėkmės!